# How do you modify IDEA IntelliJ v10.x code generators for getters and setters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, naming-conventions, javabeans, getter-setter

IntelliJ generates the following getter/setter code for boolean fields:

```
   private boolean isTest;

   public boolean isTest() {
      return isTest;
   }

   public void setTest(boolean test) {
      isTest = test;
   }
```

This too yields the same method signatures:

```
   private boolean test;

   public boolean isTest() {
      return test;
   }

   public void setTest(boolean test) {
      this.test = test;
   }
```

Great!  So far so good.  IntelliJ is following JavaBean naming conventions for boolean.

But watch what happens when you use the **object** Boolean (instead of the primitive boolean):

```
   private Boolean isTest;

   public Boolean getTest() {
      return isTest;
   }

   public void setTest(Boolean test) {
      isTest = test;
   }
```

Uh oh!  Do you see it?  It should be generating this instead (which Eclipse does):

```
   private Boolean isTest;

   public Boolean getIsTest() {
      return isTest;
   }

   public void setIsTest(Boolean isTest) {
      isTest = isTest;
   }
```

This may seem like no big deal, but this little inconsistency caused a **huge** project nightmare.  The reason is this: There are other layers and frameworks which expect to map variables **EXACTLY** to the Java class field names - otherwise it fails without custom mapping logic (painful and unnecessary).

Our team uses the is*Name* pattern for all Boolean objects.  Even our boolean database columns are named is_*name*, which gets translated to "is*Name*" using JBoss Hibernate reverse engineering tools plugin for Eclipse.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Is there some type of code generation template we can configure?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It [was reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-25268) that Eclipse generates `get<Property>` for Boolean while IDEA generated `is<Property>`. It is against the specification and users requested to fix it.

As a result of addressing this bug current IDEA version is working in accordance to the JavaBeans specification and uses such getters only for primitive `boolean` type and `get<Property>` for other types including `Boolean`.

Sorry, but there is no way to configure this behavior in IDEA.

Comment: Thank you.  I posted a follow up comment in the thread from the link you provided.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Was this changed back? I'm using version 14.1.1 and it is still generating the is<Property> for Boolean. Am I missing something?

Comment: @stepanian not sure, if you think that it's against the most recent specs, please submit a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA